# How to make smaller a background circle in a font awesome icon?

Tags: html, css, sass, font-awesome

I need to produce the following warning sign using Font Awesome:
[image]

However, I am not able to make it exactly as it is because I have like an extra border:
[image]

This is my HTML:

```
<div role="alert" class="alert alert-dismissible">
  <i id="exclamation-mark" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle extraClass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <p style="display: inline;vertical-align: middle">
    <span>Oops! Something went horribly wrong. </span> We’re really sorry. Please try that again.
  </p>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    ×
  </button>
</div>
```

This is my CSS (SCSS):

```
$color-secondary-1: #db2b4b;

p > span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: $color-secondary-1;

  i {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #ff91a5;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
  }
}

.extraClass{ 
     font-size:3em; 
}
```

[This](https://codepen.io/lmiguelvargasf/pen/weBjrB?editors=1100) is my CodePen link.

Comment: @Korgrue, I just did a slight change, but it is as I wanted. You can provide an answer explaining what you did to solve this problem in case you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flexbox:

```css
div {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #db2b4b;
}

#exclamation-mark {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
  background: #ff91a5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding:8px;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
}

.extraClass{ 
     font-size:3em; 
}

#close {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
  background: #transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding:8px;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
}

.alert {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

p{
  line-height: 0.8em;
}

p.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div role="alert" class="alert alert-dismissible">
  <i id="exclamation-mark" class="fa fa-exclamation extraClass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <div>
  <p class="bold">Oops! Something went horribly wrong.</p>
  <p>We’re really sorry. Please try that again.</p>
  </div>
  <i id="close" class="fa fa-close extraClass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response. It covers even beyond I was asking for.

Comment: why is it everything left align?

Comment: Code is adjusted. Added justify-content:space-around for flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Fix is pretty simple. Use the version of the icon without the circle, and then just add the circle manually.

Fixed: codepen.io/anon/pen/JJoZVo?editors=1100

**HTML**

```
<div role="alert" class="alert alert-dismissible">
  <i id="exclamation-mark" class="fa fa-exclamation extraClass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <p style="display: inline;vertical-align: middle">
    <span>Oops! Something went horribly wrong. </span> We’re really sorry. Please try that again.
  </p>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    ×
  </button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
$color-secondary-1: #db2b4b;

p > span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: $color-secondary-1;

  i {
    color: white;
    background: #ff91a5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding:10px;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
  }
}

.extraClass{ 
     font-size: 2em; 
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I just made some changes to match the colors.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a radial-gradient to draw your background:

```
background: radial-gradient(circle at center,white 20px,transparent 20px) no-repeat center;
```

```css
p > span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #db2b4b;
}
div i {
  font-size: 50px!important;/* for demo purpose in the snippet on SO */
  color: #ff91a5;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #ffffff 20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20px) no-repeat center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
}

.extraClass {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div role="alert" class="alert alert-dismissible">
  <i id="exclamation-mark" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle extraClass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <p style="display: inline;vertical-align: middle">
    <span>Oops! Something went horribly wrong. </span> We’re really sorry. Please try that again.
  </p>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">    ×
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: where should I add that? Inside the `i` element?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf it should be used instead `background:white;` for the i tag where the font shows ;)  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgwBbZ?editors=1100